# Printing in a loop with echo or var_dump gives three values, but dd() only gives the first value

Tags: php, laravel, echo, dd, var-dump

I have one matching row in my query.

`echo $result` gives `100`

`dd($result)` gives `1`

`var_dump($result)` gives `int(1) int(0) int(0)`

What's going on here?

Relevant code:

```
$results= DB::table('answers')->where('qid', $question->id)->where('answer', 'yes')->count();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm an idiot, it's within a foreach statement and iterating 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` is just printing `$result` array/object vars. It's like you use `toString()`. Result is '1, 0, 0' which you actually see as 100.

`var_dump` shows you three vars inside $result. `dd()` shows you and object. Click arrow in browser near '1' and it will unfold contents of the `$result`.

Comment: Makes sense. What are the 0,0 integers in this query?

Answer (score 0):

`echo` print the output, and in this case output will be the count of your query as a string 100, so you use `echo` when printing strings

`var_dump()` and `print_r()` php functions to print objects and array, where you can not print these with `echo` but the `var_dump()` function print also the data type of keys and values in arries.

this example:

```
$a = array(1, 2, array("a"));
var_dump($a);
echo '<br/>------------------------------------------<br/>';
print_r($a);
```

and the output will be:

[image]

`dd()` is a laravel helper function relate to dump and die, you can read about this [here](http://laraveldaily.com/echoing-dd-vs-var_dump-vs-print_r/)